# How to update image src when opening modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have this class component and I'm getting the data from a JSON file by using GraphQL. Everything works as expected but I find hard to update the image `src` inside of the `Modal` component when it's open. Data doesn't seems to get passed to the Modal and it shows the same image for all the cards. If I try using props it returns undefined in the `image.src`.

Any ideas or help on how to solve this would be great!!

my code:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-grid-system'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'



class ProjectsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      open: false,
    }
  }

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true, modalImage: this.props  });
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {

    const projects = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        <Row>
          {projects.projects.map(item =>(

            <Col md={6} key={item.id}>
            <div className="project-card">
              <div className="project-img-wrap">
              <img src={item.image.src.publicURL} alt="projects" onClick={this.onOpenModal} />
              </div>
              <div className="project-text-wrap">
              <span className="project-title">{item.title}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
              <img style={{maxWidth: '800px'}} src={item.image.src.publicURL} alt="projects" />
            </Modal>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        dataJson {
          projects {
            id
            title
            image {
              src {
                publicURL
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={({ dataJson }) => <ProjectsList projects={dataJson.projects} {...props} />}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made little edits to your code. That should work out. 
The problem is that you haven't passed `modalImage` from your `state` to `src` in Modal image.

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-grid-system'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'

class ProjectsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      open: false,
      modalImage: ""
    }
  }

  onOpenModal = (image) => {
    this.setState({ open: true, modalImage: image  });
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {

    const projects = this.props;
    const { open, modalImage } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        <Row>
          {projects.projects.map(item =>(

            <Col md={6} key={item.id}>
            <div className="project-card">
              <div className="project-img-wrap">
              <img src={item.image.src.publicURL} alt="projects" onClick={() => this.onOpenModal(item.image.src.publicURL)} />
              </div>
              <div className="project-text-wrap">
              <span className="project-title">{item.title}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={() => this.onCloseModal()} center>
              <img style={{maxWidth: '800px'}} src={modalImage} alt="projects" />
            </Modal>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        dataJson {
          projects {
            id
            title
            image {
              src {
                publicURL
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={({ dataJson }) => <ProjectsList projects={dataJson.projects} {...props} />}
  />
)
```